# How do you redirect error output in Powershell when executing .net methods?

Tags: .net, powershell, redirect, methods, error-handling

Why does powershell stream redirection not work with .Net calls?  I'm specifically attempting the following:

```
[system.net.dns]::Resolve("bla") 2>$null
```

That should redirect error output to null, but it doesn't.  There's tons of other ways to suppress the error, but why isn't redirection working?  How do you redirect .net output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's tons of other ways to suppress the error, but why isn't redirection working? How do you redirect .net output?

by placing your expression *inside* a PowerShell language construct, like a script-block:

```
&{ [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve('bla') } 2>$null
```

Output from the expression will still behave as expected:

```
PS> $IPHost = &{ [System.Net.DNS]::Resolve('bla') } 2>$null
PS> $IPHost -eq $null
True
PS> $IPHost = &{ [System.Net.DNS]::Resolve('www.stackoverflow.com') } 2>$null
PS> $IPHost

HostName          Aliases                 AddressList
--------          -------                 -----------
stackoverflow.com {www.stackoverflow.com} {104.16.35.249, 104.16.33.249, 104.16.37.249, 104.16.36.249...}
```